# Роутинг во вложенном компоненте React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router

Попрошу камнями не кидаться, ибо все когда то учились)
Суть такова: пишу вишлист для себя и друзей, и застрял на кажется очень глупом моменте. Вложенный компонент - это хедер с табами для навигации и кнопкой выхода. Пока реализую каркас приложения, по этому авторизация происходит просто по loggedInUser/!loggedInUser. Собственно при клике на exit button диспатчится пустая строка в loggedInUser и history.push('/login'). В отладчике вижу, что и диспатч происходит и в хистори пушится локейшн, но почему то не условие рендеринга не выполнятся. Прошу помощи знающих людей. Предполагаю, что накосячил с роутингом где то, так как читал, что BrowserRouter почему то не используется, но без него вообще не работает ничего. В общем заранее спасибо!

Точка входа:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Компонент маршрутизации:

```
interface AppProps {
    loggedInUser: string;
}

class App extends React.Component<AppProps & RouteComponentProps> {
    state = { 
        loggedInUser: ""
    }

    render() {
        const history = this.props
        return (
            <>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Segment>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route history={history} path='/login' render={() => (!this.props.loggedInUser ? <LoginPage /> : <Redirect to="/account" />)}/>
                            <Route history={history} path='/account' render={() => (this.props.loggedInUser ? <AccountPage/> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}/>
                            <Route history={history} path='/friendslist' render={() => (this.props.loggedInUser ? <FriendsList/> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}/>
                            <Redirect from='/' to='/login' />
                        </Switch>
                    </Segment>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state: StateInterface): AppProps => ({
    loggedInUser: state.loggedInUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(App))
```

Вложенный компонент(UPD: он рендерится в каждом из маршрутизируемых компонентов):

```
interface HeaderProps extends HeaderPropsFromState{
    activeItem: string;
}

interface HeaderPropsFromState{
    loggedInUser: string;
}


class Header extends React.Component<HeaderProps & RouteComponentProps> {
    state = { 
        activeItem: this.props.activeItem,
    }

    handleItemClick = (e: any, { name }: any) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

    render() {
        const { activeItem } = this.state
        const { match, history } = this.props
                return (
            <Menu pointing>
                        <Menu.Item
                            name='Friends'
                            active={activeItem === 'Friends'}
                            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
                            as={Link}
                            to="/friendslist"
                        />
                        <Menu.Item
                            name='Account'
                            active={activeItem === 'Account'}
                            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
                            as={Link}
                            to="/account"
                        />
                        {activeItem === 'Friends' &&
                            <Menu.Menu position='right'>
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    <Input icon='users' iconPosition='left' placeholder='Search users...' />
                                    {/* TODO: create function to filter by friend's name */}
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </Menu.Menu>
                        }
                        {activeItem === 'Account' &&
                            <Menu.Menu position='right'>
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    <Button basic 
                                    color='black'
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        console.log(this.props.loggedInUser)
                                        store.dispatch(setLoggedInUser({username: ""}))
                                        history.push('/login')
                                    }}
                                    >Exit</Button>
                                    {/* TODO: create function to exit from account */}
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </Menu.Menu>
                        }
                    </Menu>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state: StateInterface): HeaderPropsFromState => ({
    loggedInUser: state.loggedInUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(Header))
```

[image: UPD: просто картиночка для лучшего понимания как все выглядит :)]

Comment: ? `const history = this.props` mb `const { history } = this.props` || `const history = this.props.history`

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Comment: `<Redirect from='/' to='/login' />`

Comment: "В общем заранее пожалуйста!"©

Comment: Не очень понял что не так с редиректом из 4го комментария. :)

Comment: Как я уже говорил: после редиректа на /login не происходит проверка, `<Route history={history} path='/login' render={() => (!this.props.loggedInUser ? <LoginPage /> : <Redirect to="/account" />` при условии того, что в loggedInUser диспатчится пустая строка и редиректит обратно на /account

Comment: Боже, вот я глупец. Спасибо, нашел корень зла - буду решать)

Answer (score 0):

В общем то проблема была вовсе не в самом роутинге, а в условии редиректа.

Вместо:
`<Route history={history} path='/login' render={() => (!this.props.loggedInUser ? <LoginPage /> : <Redirect to="/account" />`

Теперь:
`<Route history={history} path='/login' render={() => loggedInStatus ? <Redirect to="/account" /> :<LoginPage />}/>`

Где this.props.loggedInUser - был строкой в которую диспатчился либо имя юзера в случае авторизации, либо !!ПУСТАЯ СТРОКА!! в случае выхода из аккаунта. Решил же проблему просто добавлением поля с булевым значением в стейт и теперь loggedInStatus - либо true, либо false.
В общем такая вот глупость, возможно кому то поможет...